# FireFox addon: pageMod how to run contentScript everytime AJAX is Done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

so i have created an add-on that finds certain strings on every page that opens, it works as it should. The only problem i have is: when a page updates its content with AJAX i don't know how to detect it and rerun my contentScriptFile.

Is there a module i should use or some type of JS listener in my content script file?

here is the pageMod:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
include: "*",
contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.9.1.min.js"), self.data.url("script.js")],

onAttach: function(worker){

    var apiKey = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.apiKey;
    var ignoreList = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.ignoreList;

    worker.port.emit("prefSet", [ignoreList, apiKey]);

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Ajax event completion will be detected by below jQuery code regardless of whether the Ajax event completed successfully or failed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      alert("AJAX call completed");
    });
});
```

To make JQuery available to FireFox Add-On, please install [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jquery/) firefox add-on/extension

Comment: The code works! But it wont work in my content script. it just doesn't fire off. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, no idea on FireFox add-on development.

Comment: thats ok, I still learned that there is such a thing as .ajaxComplete()  :)

Comment: Above syntax uses JQuery. To make JQuery available to FireFox Add-On, you need to install this extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jquery/

Comment: thats a good idea when developing just for myself (good to know, thanx:)), but when i release my addon I cant know if all the users will have this installed.

Comment: JQuery add-on adds reference of jQuery CDN url. So you need to do same inside your add-on so that it is not dependent on other add-on.  e.g.  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js